# How do I loop through a split list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, split

I am trying to loop through each item in a list using this;

```
def squareEach(list):

     for num in list.split():
         squares = []
         square = int(num) * int(num)
         squares.append(square)
    return squares

def main():

    nums = input("Please enter a list of numbers: ")
    print("The squares of the numbers are:", squareEach(nums))
```

But anytime I run the code, only the last item in the list is squared.

Please enter a list of numbers: 1 2 3 6
The squares of the numbers are: [36]

Does anyone know how I get the loop to square each number in the list?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `squares = []` outside the for loop. The squares array is getting reset each time. This solution requires no changes to the `main()` method.

new code:

```py
def squareEach(list):
    squares = []
    for num in list.split():
        square = int(num) * int(num)
        squares.append(square)
    return squares
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was the simplest and it helped print the output I needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize the squares list outside the loop
2. convert the user input to a list of numbers before passing it to `squareEach`.

```
def squareEach(nums):
    squares = [] 
    for num in nums:
        square = int(num) * int(num)
        squares.append(square)
    return squares

def main():
    user_input = input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by spaces: ")
    nums = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
    print("The squares of the numbers are:", squareEach(nums))

main()
```

**Output**

```
Please enter a list of numbers separated by spaces: 1 2 3 6
The squares of the numbers are: [1, 4, 9, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way:

```
def square(nums_list):
    return [float(num) * float(num) for num in nums_list.split()]

def main():
    user_list = input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by spaces: ")
    print("The squares of the numbers are:", square(user_list))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter the list entered by the user to discard invalid characters, and you also want that if a number entered is integer its result squared is not shown with decimal part (.0), you can do something a little more elaborate like this:

```
def square_v2(user_data):
    separated = [data for data in user_data.split()]
    numbers = []
    for element in separated:
        # discard non-numeric characters
        try:
            numbers.append(float(element))
        except:
            pass

    square_list=[]
    for n in numbers:
        # filtering integers and floats
        if(int(n)==n):
            square_list.append(int(n*n))
        else:
            square_list.append( n*n )

    return square_list



def main():
    user_list = input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by spaces: ")
    print("The squares of the numbers are:", square_v2(user_list))

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

`squares = []` should be initialized before the loop. Initializing inside the loop will initialize every time the loop runs.